# When you lose control of Conjure Elemental, is it still hostile towards your enemies or just you?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, summoning

Conjure Elemental:

> If your concentration is broken, the elemental doesn’t disappear. Instead, you lose control of the elemental, it **becomes hostile** toward you and your companions, and it might attack.

Does this mean it becomes indifferent against its previous targets, and hostile toward you, or hostile toward everyone?

In other words, would it stop attacking the creature that has already damaged it several times just to come after you, or not?

Comment: Do you ask as a player or as a DM?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The elemental doesn't *become* indifferent against its previous targets. It *was* indifferent. The only thing that made it attack the target was the caster's will. Now, when the caster's concentration is broken, their will enslaves the elemental no more.

The elemental is angry toward the caster, who pulled it out of its plane. It even *might* attack the caster or one of his/her allies. But nothing in the rules says it must (or will) attack. What the elemental will do is up to the DM.

Comment: It _was_ indifferent when it was summoned, but that Ogre hurt it since. It is standing right next to it when the control is ended. Why not keep attacking it?

Comment: @András because the caster is the first priority target? The elemental has 5-6 INT, it might be enough to understand it was fighting with the orge only because the caster said so.

Comment: Mind you, if the ogre hit him with an attack of opportunity while the elemental was moving away (An ogre wouldn't exactly know the elemental is no longer under control), then said elemental might be a bit cross

Comment: @QDust well, it doesn't contradict the rules: "it becomes hostile toward you and your companions, and it might attack".

Comment: Quite. All in all, I would favor whatever makes for the best narrative. Summon a fire elemental into a frozen wasteland to fight a white dragon  and it'll understandably be fairly upset with the wizard who pulled it out of its comfy plane of existence. Edit: Of course, it should go without saying that this is all, as you said, the DM's call, wonderfully so.

Answer (score 3):

**It's just hostile to you and your companions.**

By RAW, the *conjure elemental* will only make the elemental friendly or hostile to the caster and their companions. It doesn't affect, under any circumstances, the disposition of the elemental to any other creatures.

I would say that the intent of this effect is generally that a hostile elemental stops being beneficial to the caster and becomes a problem. So as a DM I would generally have the elemental focus on making life bad for the caster rather than continuing to obey the orders it was given. The elemental likely would have no feelings one way or the other about the creature it was previously attacking.